# Which event can I use to detect remote form submission into sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm using the WordPress Contact Form 7 plugin as a website contact form. The user's date is submitted to a google spreadsheet and stored as a new row.

Which event can detect that that information was added?

I tried the onChange and onEdit functions to hook this event but didn't get any success.

Comment: isnt this what you are looking for? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EnJz.png

Answer (score 0):

[Google Apps Script events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) doesn't include an event for changes made by an API. If your WordPress Contact Form 7 is open source and already using Google Apps Script or the Google Sheets API add to it an adaptation of the code that you planned to use on you onChange / onEdit functions.